# R - Running a for loop through multiple groups (Reset)

Tags: r, for-loop

My dataframe consists of three columns:

- customerID: shows an unique ID for each customer.
- buy: "1" if the customer bought a certain product and "0" if they didn't.
- loy: Indicates the grade of "loyalty" of the customer. The value changes depending if the customer has **previously** bought (or not) the product.

The same customer can buy the product multiple times.

The construction of the variable "loy" goes in the following way for each observation [i]:

> 0.9*buy[i-1] + 0.1*loy[i-1]

This is the piece of code I have until now:

```
dta <- data.frame(
  customerID = c("10","10","10","11","11","11","12","12","12","13","13", "13", "14", 
          "14", "14", "15", "15", "15", "16", "16", "16"),
    buy = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
           0, 0, 1)
)

dta$loy <- 0

n=nrow(dta)

for(i in 2:n){
  dta$loy[i] <- dta$buy[i-1]*0.9 + 0.1*dta$loy[i-1]
}
```

(The first value of "loy" for each customer is supposed to be fixed to "0")

I need to construct the variable "loy" **for each customer**. That means, the loop has to reset every time it passes to a new customerID, but I don't know how to do it.

With the code I have until now, the loop keeps going for all of the observations.

It's worth to mention that **this dataframe was created from scratch just for the ease of this question**. I have another set of data with over 2000 customerID's, on which I plan to apply the solution of this simplified problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a loop inside another loop. This solution depends on your data being sorted by customerID and time.

```
ids <- unique(dta$customerID)

for(i in ids){
    # location of ith customer's records
    index <- which(dta$customerID == i)
    # calculate running loyalty score
    for (j in index[-1]) {
        dta[j, "loy"] <- dta[
            j - 1, "buy"]*0.9 + 0.1*dta[
                j - 1, "loy"]
    }
}
dta
#    customerID buy  loy
# 1          10   1 0.00
# 2          10   1 0.90
# 3          10   1 0.99
# 4          11   1 0.00
# 5          11   0 0.90
# 6          11   0 0.09
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

dta%>% 
  group_by(customerID) %>% 
  mutate(tmp = 0.9 * lag(buy, default = 0), 
         loy = tmp + 0.1 * lag(tmp, default = 0)) %>% 
  select(-tmp) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 21 x 3
   customerID   buy   loy
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 10             1  0   
 2 10             1  0.9 
 3 10             1  0.99
 4 11             1  0   
 5 11             0  0.9 
 6 11             0  0.09
 7 12             0  0   
 8 12             1  0   
 9 12             1  0.9 
10 13             1  0   
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! This also solved my problem. 

Much appreciated